# How to set notification channel when sending messages via rest api?

Tags: firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, notification-channel

I've been implementing Notification Channels in my android app to support recent android versions.

You can set the notification channel id when sending messages from the firebase web console, but I was not able to find out how to set the channel id when sending messages via fcm rest api.

Notification channels are not mentioned in the reference (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/fcm/rest/v1/projects.messages), but I am pretty sure there must be a way to set the channel id.

Comment: In order to do that, you must understand the steps given in the link above.

Comment: I am already using the rest api to send messages, no problems with that. Just looking for a key/field to put the channel id in ... or am I missing something concept-wise?

Comment: Maybe you can take the channel id from a previous activity?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The key name I was missing is **android_channel_id**

I found the key name in the *Legacy HTTP Server Protocol docs* (https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)

Comment: Thanks dear, but this solution did not work for me. Thanks again.

Comment: FYI, when actually sending a message, the parameter name needs to be "channel_id":  Example : android: {
                notification: {
                    title:title,
                    body: message,
                    channel_id:'high_importance_channel'
                }
            },